# Set up React component to listen to socket.io

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, socket.io

I want my React component to listen to events from socket.io. My code works if I have the HTML files include:

`<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

and then the component's constructor() has:

`this.socket = io(); // eslint-disable-line no-undef`

The HTML file retrieves the proper socket.io client code from my Express server, and everything's fine.

But this feels so cheesy. I hate to rely on the global window name space to find the io() function. What's the best practice for letting a React component connect through socket.io to the server? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you pass the `io` function in props? And then connect during `componentDidMount`

Comment: That would help in testing to, as you could pass in a mock io function that you control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a bundler like Webpack or Browserify, you can use [`socket.io-client`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/).

For instance:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.socket = io();
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works great! And @martriay's suggestion of using lifecycle methods (`componentWillMount`) gives more fine-grained control of when the socket gets connected/disconnected. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would create the socket on `componentWillMount` and `setState` on the desired event callback.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing. I used the componentWillMount method. I also added a connection detection:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const socket = io(uri)

  socket.on('update', (data) => {
    this.setState({ data, connected: true })
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    this.setState({ connected: false })
  });

  socket.on('reconnect', () => {
    this.setState({ connected: true })
  });
}
```